# HTTP Error 404: Not Found Try to open in browser (While web crawling)

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler

```
#Get tweets by username(s):

import GetOldTweets3 as got

tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername("barackobama whitehouse")\
                                           .setMaxTweets(2)
tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)[0]
print(tweet.text)
```

Hello all,

i tried this code and it gave me this error, please help :

*got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)[0]
print(tweet.text)
An error occured during an HTTP request: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Try to open in browser: https://twitter.com/search?q=%20from%3Abarackobama%20whitehouse&src=typd
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit*

Comment: This is because the library you are using is not using the official Twitter API and is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue with code .You can check the detail on below link
https://github.com/Mottl/GetOldTweets3/issues/98